# A segmentation fault with the use of argv

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, argv

I am not sure what the problem is with my code. It was all working until I tried to use the argv command and then when I went to execute i get a segmentation fault. please let me know your thougths.

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <string>
   using namespace std;
  
  
   int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  
      vector<string> nums;
      vector<string> single {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
      vector<string> second {"eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};
      vector<string> twos {"twenty", "thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};
 
      string num;
      string s;
 
      s = argv[1];
 
      while (s != "quit") {
          nums.push_back(s);
      }
     int b =s.length();
      int a = stoi(s);
 
          if (a< 10){
                 cout << "Number" << s << "is written as" << single[a] << '\n';
          }
          else if (a < 100){
              int temp10 = a / 10;
              int temp1 = a - temp10*10;
 
              if (temp1 == 0){
                  cout << "Oops! Entered a 0 in the number";
              }else{
                  cout << "Number" << s << "is written as" << single[temp10] << single[temp1] << '\n';
              }
          }
          else if (b == 3){
              int temp100 = a / 100;
              int temp10  = a - temp100*100;
              temp10  = temp10 / 10;
              int temp1   = a - temp100*100 - temp10*10;
                 if (temp10 == 1){
                       cout << "Oops! Entered a 1 in the tens place";
 
                  }else if (temp10 == 0 || temp1 == 0){
                      cout << "Oops! Entered a 0 in the number";
                  }else{
                      cout << "Number" << s << "is written as" << single[temp10] << single[temp1] << '\n';
                  }
          }
          else if (b == 4){
              int temp1000 = a / 1000;
              int temp100 = a - temp1000*1000;
              temp100 = temp100 / 100;
              int temp10  = a - temp1000*1000 - temp100*100;
              temp10  = temp10 / 10;
              int temp1   = a - temp1000*1000 - temp100*100 - temp10*10;
              if (temp10 == 1){
                  cout << "Oops! Entered a 1 in the tens place";
 
              }else if (temp1000 == 0 || temp100 == 0 || temp10 == 0 || temp1 == 0){
                  cout << "Oops! Entered a 0 in the number";
              }else{
                  cout << "Number" << s << "is written as" << temp1000 << "thousand" << temp100 << "hundred" << single[temp10] << si
    ngle[temp1] << '\n';
              }
          }
```

the point of the code is to take in the users command line input and the spell out the number in words.

Comment: Any time you use `argv` without first checking `argc` to confirm that it's safe you're asking for trouble. `argv`: list of arguments. `argc`: number of arguments in list.

Comment: You need to check argc before referencing argv[1]. If no arg was supplied referencing argv[1] will be undefined, eg segfault.

Comment: i can imagine what if this condition ** while (s != "quit") {nums.push_back(s);} ** not getting false, infinite loop maybe?

Comment: @KenWhite why you think so? isn't operator== a part of the standards and it returns lhs.compare(rhs) == 0?

Comment: @OP What line of code is the segmentation fault occurring? -- *please let me know your thougths.* -- You're supposed to be doing this.  Fixing the problem is one thing, but at the very least, you should make an effort to debug the code to identify *where* the problem is.  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in potentially infinite loop `while (s != "quit"){nums.push_back(s);}`, what if **s** is really not **quit**?. infinite loops are more than likely to cause segmentation faults.

warning : at the line `int a = stoi(s);` you'll have **[terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument' what(): stoi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070101/terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-stdinvalid-argument-what-s)**

Comment: So if i remove the while statement so its just nums.push_back(s) I still receive a segmentation fault. I have looked into the link but i do not understand enough to implement the fix for that problem.

Comment: i don't know what's the problem so, i tried to compile your code and run on onlinegdb.com and no problem with it, can you please post your segmentation fault message if you think it has any details?